# Not able to understand a logarithm conversion

Tags: math, time-complexity, logarithm, recurrence

I was going through slides of an algorithm class and came across following.

> T(n) = 2T(n^(1/2)) + lg n
>
> Rename: m = lg n => n = 2^m 
>   T (2^m) = 2T(2^(m/2)) + m
>
> Rename: S(m) = T(2^m) S(m) = 2S(m/2) + m

Can any one explain me how did the last equation come ? I'm not able to understand how S(m/2) came. Thank you.

Comment: I spent 1.5 hrs before posting this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just an argument substitution.

You have `S(m) = T(f(m)), where f(m) = 2^m`. Substitute m with m/2 and you'll get

```
S(m/2) = T(f(m/2)), f(m/2) = 2^(m/2)
```

Now you may rewrite left part `T(f(m/2)) = T(2^(m/2)) = S(m/2)`

Comment: Thank you. That helped. It did not look trivial to me as they confused me with using m at both places.